# Settings schema 'io.elementary.code.settings' does not contain a key named 'smart-cut-copy'

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, code, elementary-project

Unable to open elementary's built in text-editor: code.

When launching from dock, it never opens while the cursor gets replaced by a circular spinner for 10-15 seconds.
When launched from terminal, it gives the following error -
[GLib-GIO] Settings schema 'io.elementary.code.settings' does not contain a key named 'smart-cut-copy' [1](https://github.com/elementary/code/issues/766) 31744 trace trap io.elementary.code

I tried `sudo apt install --reinstall io.elementary.code`, but it didn't fix anything, but it did give a warning on reinstallation

it didn't resolve, but it did give a warning on reinstallation

`No such key 'button-layout' in schema 'org.gnome.mutter:Pantheon' as specified in override file '/usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/20_elementary.pantheon.wm.gschema.override'; ignoring override for this key. No such key 'enable-animations' in schema 'org.gnome.mutter:Pantheon' as specified in override file '/usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/20_elementary.pantheon.wm.gschema.override'; ignoring override for this key.`

I've also updated to new version of code released today, but it doesn't fix this issue. I tried installation by cloning the repository, but it also gives same errors.

[Github Issue](https://github.com/elementary/code/issues/766)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you'll find in the linked Github issue - likely one of the schema settings is interfering with settings for elementary's code app. Since Code is unable to find it's settings it's crashing; it can be fixed if `XDG_DATA_DIR` is set to a value so that Code gets correct settings. In my case I, initially, had to add following in my terminal's shell startup script (e.g. .zshrc for zsh or .bashrc for bash) -

`$ export XDG_DATA_DIRS="/usr/share:$XDG_DATA_DIRS"`

but on further reading it I found out that in order to launch it from the dock, I'd need to put it inside `~/.xsessionrc`

`$ echo export 'XDG_DATA_DIRS="/usr/share:$XDG_DATA_DIRS"' >> ~/.xsessionrc`

Just make sure if something goes awry, you should be able to revert the changes to `xsessionrc`

Comment: Negative. Adding  `export XDG_DATA_DIRS="/usr/share:$XDG_DATA_DIRS"` to ~/.xsessionrc does not solve the problem. Upgrading io.elementary.code still keeps missing keys.

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the **20_elementary.pantheon.wm.gschema.override** file

```
sudo nano /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/20_elementary.pantheon.wm.gschema.override
```

Then comment out

```
#button-layout
```

Run the installer again

```
sudo apt install --reinstall io.elementary.code
```

Then edit the **20_elementary.pantheon.wm.gschema.override** file again and uncomment the **button-layout** line